# Calling function from an object with event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a view model something like this:

```
CANVAS = getElementById...

RemixView = function(attrs) {
     this.model = attrs.model;
     this.dragging = false;
     this.init();
};

RemixView.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        CANVAS.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
    },
    handleClick: function(ev) {
        var obj = this.getHoveredObject(ev);
    },
    getHoveredObject: function(ev) {}
    ...
    ...
}
rv = new RemixView()
```

the problem is my when clickHandler event fired, this object is being equal to **CANVAS** object, **not RemixView**. So I get an error that says:

> this.getHoveredObject is not a function

What is correct approach at that stuation?

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach is to use a simple closure for the callback and capture the appropriate value of `this` in a local variable that the closure can reference:

```
RemixView.prototype = {
    init: function(this) {
        var _this = this;
        CANVAS.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
            return _this.handleClick(ev);
        });
    },
    //...
};
```

You could also use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make a bound function (as [user123444555621](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067094/479863) does):

```
RemixView.prototype = {
    init: function(this) {
        CANVAS.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick.bind(this));
    },
    //...
};
```

Or, if you want to use ES6, you could use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
RemixView.prototype = {
    init: function(this) {
        CANVAS.addEventListener("click", ev => this.handleClick(ev));
    },
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the handler function:

```
CANVAS.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick.bind(this));
```

Note that this may not work in older browsers, but there are [polyfills](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js) for those.

Comment: problem is not about binding event, calling **getHoveredObject** method from **handleClick** method.

Comment: My answer is not about binding event.

Answer (score 0):

Make `prototype` a function.

```
RemixView.prototype = function () {
    init: function() {
        CANVAS.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
    },
    handleClick: function(ev) {
        var obj = this.getHoveredObject(ev);
    } ///...
//...
}
```

Comment: here you're defining prototype as function but behaving it like object. i think init: must be this.init = function() { ... } ?